# how to declare/define a function and call it inside the groovy script

Tags: jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

After reading many threads I am stuck on this very simple task

Want to declare/define a function in which I can call it later for for other stage task's inside the pipeline.

```
parameters:[
    string(name: 'shop_name', value:"abc"),
    string(name: 'location', value:"AUS"),
    string(name: 'pincode', value:"12345"),
           ]
```

and want to call this in couple of stages in the pipeline

```
stage('shop'){
     try{
     //will call another Jenkins Job by passing below values 
     parameters:[
           string(name: 'shop_name', value:"abc"),
           string(name: 'location', value:"AUS"),
           string(name: 'pincode', value:"12345"),
           ]
  }catch(error){
    retry(2){
    //will call another Jenkins Job by passing below values 
    parameters:[
           string(name: 'shop_name', value:"abc"),
           string(name: 'location', value:"AUS"),
           string(name: 'pincode', value:"12345"),
           ]
  }
 }
}
```

instead of specifying the string parameters every time, want to declare/define that as a function and call it in the pipeline.

Comment: Do you want to trigger another jenkins jobs from stages? is this what you want?

Comment: not exactly, want to assign set of string value to a variable/function and then use that to call it later in the stages..